# RemoveAllObjects equivalent fror NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

I know how I would achieve this using NSMutableArray, but whats the correct way of emptying a whole array of class NSArray. I need to do this because I need to reload a tableView. Im using ARC.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what made you think that a tableview **has** to use `NSArray` as its data source?

Comment: @borrrden I don't think that, but I'm working with someone else's code at work, and I don't want to change more than necessary

Comment: If you want to reload a tableView, like you said, why don't you just do [tableView reloadData]?

Comment: you do know why NSMutableArray has Mutable in his name, while NSArray doesn't, right?

Comment: @njzk2 I do, but I was wondering if anyone had a solution for it since I'm not just wanting to remove one object or add one. I wanted to empty the whole array.

Comment: Carlton Gibson's answer seems to give the only 2 possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *yourArray  = [ whatever objects you have ]

//to empty this array
yourArray = [NSArray array];
```

Comment: I found your solution to be optimal even before you posted the answer. So.. the points goes to you for having the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

NSArray is an immutable type. You cannot alter it's contents after creation.

Either use an NSMutableArray or replace it with a new (empty) NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

`NSArray` is an immutable (unchangeable) class so there is no way to remove elements from the array.  Basically, you will have to throw the array away and replace it with a new `NSArray`.  Alternatively, you could just use an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Do I still have to release it if Im using ARC? Im not used to using it so sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Give it a try, the compiler will not allow you to call "release" in ARC mode

Comment: Sorry, missed that you are using ARC. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You cant empty a non mutable NSArray, the best approach is to get a mutable copy of your array:

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[yourArr mutableCopy];
[arr removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: This will not empty the original array

Comment: Yes i know ;) just because you cant empty a non mutable NSArray.